# Weird linker error undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class with no virtual function, this class contains another class, here is their definitions:

```
class StorageManager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
protected:

    class AbstractWrapper {
    public:
        virtual void action1() = 0;
        virtual void action2() = 0;
        virtual void action3() = 0;
        virtual ~AbstractWrapper() {}
    };

    class AbstractStorage {
    public:
        virtual QSharedPointer<AbstractWrapper> getWrapper(QString key) = 0;
        virtual QSharedPointer<AbstractWrapper> newWrapper(QString key) = 0;
        virtual void deleteWrapper(QString key) = 0;
        virtual ~AbstractStorage() {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    class Wrapper {
    public:
        virtual void action1() { /* do stuff */ }
        virtual void action2() { /* do stuff */ }
        virtual void action3() { /* do stuff */ }
        virtual ~Wrapper() {}
    private:
        T * realContent;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class Storage {
    public:
        virtual QSharedPointer<AbstractWrapper> getWrapper(QString key)
        {
            return new Wrapper<T>(storage.value(key));
        }
        virtual QSharedPointer<AbstractWrapper> newWrapper(QString key)
        {
            T * tmp = new T();

            QObject::connect(tmp,         SIGNAL(signal(int)),
                             &dispatcher, SLOT(slot(int)));
            storage.insert(key, tmp);
            return new Wrapper<T>(tmp);
        }

        virtual void deleteWrapper(QString key)
        {
            T * tmp = storage.value(key);
            disconnect(tmp, SIGNAL(signal(int)),
                       &dispatcher, SLOT(slot(int)));
            delete tmp;
            storage.remove(key);
        }

        virtual ~Storage() {}
    private:
        QHash<QString, T *> storage;
    };

private:

    static Storage<ClassA> classAStorage;
    static Storage<ClassB> classBStorage;
    static Storage<ClassC> classCStorage;

    static StorageManager dispatcher;

public:
    static AbstractStorage * getStorage(int classid)
    {
             if(classid == 'A') return &classAStorage;
        else if(classid == 'B') return &classBStorage;
        else if(classid == 'C') return &classCStorage;
        else throw std::exception();
    }

    public void connectDispatcher(QObject * receiver, const char * method)
    {
        connect(&dispatcher, SIGNAL(dispatch_signal(int)), receiver, method);
    }

public slots:
    void slot(int output)
    {
        emit dispatch_signal(output);
    }

signals:
    void dispatch_signal(int);

}
```

I have also a .cpp file with all the static initiliazations.

When compiling this I have no compilation errors. But one linker errors :

```
undefined reference to `vtable for StorageManager'
```

This error is labeled on the class definition line :

```
class StorageManager : public QObject {
```

I know this kind of error is related to pure virtual member not overloaded, but I don't see this errors in my code...

Thanks for your help

---

EDIT:

Answer: The file was not compiled by moc.
Solution: Delete file from project, add the same class using "Add New...", "C++ Class". Triple check that you choose QObject as parent class.

This is probably a QtCreator related bug, this appens with QtCreator 3.3.2 from revision 3af3fe7ad3

Comment: Did you run qmake before building the project?

Comment: Yes, I work with QtCreator (other Q_OBJECT class works without problem). I did a full rebuild before posting this question ;)

Comment: Is the header listed in `HEADERS` in the `.pro` file?

Comment: Yes, I will try to remove it, compile. Re-add it and recompile.

Comment: Ok, for some weird reasons the file was not compiled by the MOC. Delete it from the project and re-add it solves the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found !

The header file was not compiled by the moc compiler but was in the `.pro` file.

To solve the problem: delete header and source file from your project. Clean your project. Build your project.

Then add your class using QtCreator assistant :

- Add New...
- C++ Class
- Name your class and choose QObject as base class

Then rebuild your project, that should be fine.

---

This is probably a QtCreator related bug, this appens with QtCreator 3.3.2 from revision 3af3fe7ad3.